# Mongodb Association using koajs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, koa

I'm currently migrating my project form sails to koajs,
and i can't figure out how mongodb association is working in koajs.

I tried this code hoping that it will run, but it's hopeless.

```
properties.find({}).populate('user').sort('updatedAt DESC')
```

I'm currently using co-monk as a middleware. [co-monk](https://www.npmjs.org/package/monk)

Is there any middleware that can i use? So that i can use the mongodb association?

I tried searching at google but it gives me nothing.

Hopes that there is a solution.
Thanks guys.

Comment: this `populate` feature is part of `mongoose`, a different framework that doesn't support generators natively (without plugins).
In `co-monk` you would need to handle the associations yourself, with separate queries.